# JavaScript wont change a html value for input

Tags: javascript, html

```
    function editcomment(openid) {
      var pageid = "<?= $ID ?>";
      var commentid = "p" + openid;
      console.log(openid);
      console.log(commentid);
      console.log(pageid);
      var commentcontent = document.getElementById(commentid).innerHTML; <-- this is what i want the input to display
      console.log(commentcontent); <-- checking the value proves thats its fine and not blank
      document.getElementById("commenttext").value = commentcontent; <-- this wont change the input just refuses to
      document.getElementById("commenteditid").value = openid;
      document.getElementById("postid").value = pageid;
      document.getElementById("editcommentdiv").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

the code will change the input "postid" but wont change "commenteditid"
what it changes :

```
<form action="php/edit-comment.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<input id="postid" type="hidden" name="idinput" value=""> <-- but these will
<input type="text" id="commenttext" name="commenttext" value=""> <-- this wont change at all 
<input type="hidden" id="commenteditid" name="commenteditid" value=""> <-- but these will
<button id="sendbutton" type="submit"  onclick="preparetext()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

any idea how to fix this problem as the code seems to be fine, just the value wont change

Comment: Try using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, it's quite possible that line breaks/etc. are preventing you from seeing the value set.

Comment: that didn't work @RobM it can get the input okay it just wont put it into the input

Comment: You defined the function `editcomment()`, but you didn't show us how did you call it, i.e. what was the argument `openid` in your code. Please clarify this so that we can help.

Comment: @WaisKamal its called by the commandline at the moment for example "editcomment('commentidhere')" the code sets the other two inputs fine just not this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
document.getElementById("commenttext").setAttribute('value', commentcontent);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/egj31e4g/5

or here:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  let commentid = 'commentid';
  let commentcontent = document.getElementById(commentid).innerHTML;
  alert(commentcontent);
  document.getElementById("commenttext").setAttribute('value', commentcontent);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<form action="php/edit-comment.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="idinput" value="111">
  <!-- but these will -->
  <input type="text" id="commenttext" name="commenttext" value="222">
  <!-- <-- this wont change at all -->
  <input type="text" id="commenteditid" name="commenteditid" value="333">
  <!-- but these will -->
  <!-- <button id="sendbutton" type="submit"  onclick="preparetext()">Submit</button> -->
</form>

<p id='commentid' style="display: none">commentid value</p>
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it is there a reason why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

Is the "commenttext" the ID of the comment text? If you have multiple comments wouldn't that conflict? That could very well be the reason. In the first part: You're doing `var commentcontent = document.getElementById(commentid).innerHTML;` which is a specific comment found by it's ID, but if all of the comments have an ID for "commenttext" then getElementById simply takes the first element with that id it sees. So that could be the reason? Unless you're doing this on a separate page where there are no other comments, but that doesn't make sense since you're retrieving the comment info by taking it's innerHTML.